# How to make DHCP srver from PC with Ubuntu Server 19.10? (PPPoE connection)

Tags: server, 19.10, dhcp, pppoe

How to create DHCP server from PC with Ubuntu Server 19.10?

PC has two ethernet cards. (enp3s5 - lan, enp3s6 - wan)

`pppoeconf` is missing after installing the Ubuntu Server 19.10.

How to configure this file for PPPoE-connection: `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`?

[image]